# Correct use of split() to create js 2-d array containing date from string with ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to make a live updated chart using ajax to supply data and Google Charts to present. The data are an array where one column is in date format. I tried to read up on JSON.parse but noted that date objects are not parsed and since I am in full control of the ajax output, why not send a string and then split and make an array at the receiving end? This is what I thought would work:

File "ajaxdemo.php" supplying data by ajax. The rows are arbitrarily separated by "/" and the columns by ":"

```
<?php 
echo "
2018,2,14:1/
2018,2,15:2/
2018,2,16:3";
exit;
?>
```

file requesting data and creating array for chart. `split()` is used twice to extract the elements of the 2-D table array.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

jQuery(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});

 var indata = [];

 $.get("ajaxdemo.php",
   {},
   function(data,status){
      var datarray = data.split("/");//make each row an element in an array
      var dl = datarray.length;
      for(i=0;i<dl;i++){
        var subarray = datarray[i].split(":");//split each row into columns
        subarray[0] = new Date(subarray[0]);
       indata.push(subarray);
      }

     ;
   });

   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDemo);

   function drawDemo() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
      alert(indata[0][0]);
      data.addRows(indata);
      var options = {
        hAxis: {
          title: 'x'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'y'
        },
        backgroundColor: '#FFE4DD'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
 });
});
 </script>
 <div id="chart_div"></div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

The resulting array `indata`seems to behave as a js array in every which way. And  I can check that the date objects get created ok since they display the dates when put in an alert box `alert(indata[0][0]);` for instance. But the line `data.addRows(indata)`gives an error complaining about type mismatch. What should I do, and why?

Comment: can you attach the error please?

Comment: The js console of Chrome dev tools said: "jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:75 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Type mismatch. Value 1 does not match type number in column index 1
    at gvjs_fn (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:75)..." etc

Answer (score 0):

I might as well take this down, but for now...

The offending thing here was not the date but the other column, which was to be shown on the Y axis. It has to be converted to number format.

```
$.get("ajaxdemo.php",
   {},
   function(data,status){
      var datarray = data.split("/");//make each row an element in an array
      var dl = datarray.length;
      for(i=0;i<dl;i++){
        var subarray = datarray[i].split(":");//split each row into columns
        subarray[0] = new Date(subarray[0]);
        subarray[1] = Number(subarray[1]); //•••Fixes the error ••• 
       indata.push(subarray);
      }

     ;
   });
```

Simple thing really...